# Facebook Share response if successful or not removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

For sharing posts I used the URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed with `redirect_uri` which appended a `post_id` parameter to the `redirect_uri` when the post was really shared and not clicked on the cancel button.

After Facebook announced to introduce versions of APIs and changes to the current API,
the `/dialog/feed` will be deprecated so I need to convert.

Now the URL is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share but there is no longer a parameter added whether the post was shared or not. Any suggestions to fix that?

I read that there is a `object_id` now but just for `share_open_graph` and if the user is logged in into an Facebook app and has granted permissions for `publish_actions`.